# How to distinct values on multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am using SQL and have a table with columns `Tz, Suma, Erzor`, `CreateDate` (DateTime) and a few more.

I want to take all the columns mentioned above for specific userID distinct by `CreateDate`, also I want to distinct `Suma` and `Erzor`. The issue is that because of the variety of `CreateDate` values, I get the  different result then expected.

My query is in a stored procedure which gets `@Tz` (rn) as input parameter which looks like this (based from google research I've done) :

```
SELECT 
    Suma,
    Ezror,
    DateCreate
FROM
    (SELECT 
         Suma,
         Erzor,
         DateCreate,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DateCreate ORDER BY Suma) rn
     FROM 
         UsrHist) t
WHERE 
    rn = 956321478
```

So if there is for the above rn (@Tz) duplicated `Suma` and `Ezror` reduce to 1 and get the latest `DateCreate` from it and order by it desc., also get all fields for this record, also take the last (top) 10.

This data:

```
Tz          Suma     Erzor    DateCreate
-------------------------------------------------------
956321478   7785     30       26-04-2019 13:40:15.563
956321478   7785     30       26-04-2019 13:45:30.785
956321478   7785     50       26-04-2019 12:45:30.152
956321478   7785     50       25-04-2019 16:43:10.652
956321478   7785     10       26-04-2019 13:55:18.752
956321478   7785     90       26-04-2019 12:51:50.359
956321478   7785     60       25-04-2019 19:32:20.715
```

The result needs to be:

```
Tz          Suma     Erzor    DateCreate
-----------------------------------------------------
956321478   7785     30       26-04-2019 13:45:30.785
956321478   7785     50       26-04-2019 16:43:10.652
956321478   7785     10       26-04-2019 13:55:18.752
956321478   7785     90       26-04-2019 12:51:50.359
956321478   7785     60       25-04-2019 19:32:20.715
```

I don't mind about the time, the date is important though

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the partition and order for the row_number could be changed.
Then limit on the row_number.

```
SELECT TOP 10 Suma, Ezror, DateCreate
FROM
(
    SELECT Tz, Suma, Erzor, DateCreate,
     Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY Tz, Suma, Ezror ORDER BY DateCreate DESC) AS rn
    FROM UsrHist
    WHERE Tz = 956321478
) q
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY DateCreate DESC
```